# Mysql joining pivot tables with count then condition

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to get a count on the pivot table which has been left joined then run a where clause on the pivot table again to filter out the rest that are not required?

Below is what I have so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
      (
          SELECT COUNT(user_id) as Count
          FROM group_buys
      ) GroupBuy
      LEFT JOIN group_buy_users GroupBuysUser
          ON GroupBuysUser.group_buy_id = GroupBuy.id
WHERE GroupBuysUser.user_id = {$this->Auth->user('id')}
```

I found a solution:

```
SELECT *
        FROM group_buys GroupBuy
        LEFT JOIN group_buy_users GroupBuysUser
        ON GroupBuysUser.group_buy_id = GroupBuy.id
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT group_buy_id, COUNT(user_id) as Count
            FROM group_buy_users
            GROUP BY group_buy_id
        ) GroupBuysUserCount
        ON GroupBuysUserCount.group_buy_id = GroupBuy.id
        LEFT JOIN group_buy_merchant_offers GroupBuysMerchantOffer
        ON GroupBuysMerchantOffer.group_buy_id = GroupBuy.id
        WHERE GroupBuysUser.user_id = {$this->Auth->user('id')}
        GROUP BY GroupBuy.id
        HAVING GroupBuy.expiry_date > NOW()
        ORDER BY GroupBuysMerchantOffer.bid_price ASC
```

Basically I just had to do a LEFT JOIN a dummy table which had count already with group buy on its id then where clause on the user which the user_id belongs to then group by again on Groupbuy.id to get rid of duplicates. I added having expiry as I had to remove all the older groupbuys that are expired but this added the count of group users from group_buy_users table then again group_buy_users table as it is so I can retrieve other details aswell.

Comment: Probably but I'm a bit confused as you seem to have the basic technique already as select * From (select ...) as dummyTable. What am I missing?

Comment: @JohnKim your question is not very clear, can you post some sample data or create a [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with a working data model?  Please also post the desired result.